# Sorting in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Suppose I create a pandas data frame as :

`my_newobj = pd.DataFrame({'b': [4, 7, -3, 2], 'a': [0, 4, 7, 1]})`

And I try to pass a list to the `by` parameter for sorting values in each column name as such:

`my_newobj.sort_values(by=['b', 'a'])`

I understand the primary sorting done on column name **b** but why isn't secondary sorting performed on column **a** accordingly as well even after passing a list of column names to sort on?

Am I understanding something wrong here?

Comment: It only uses the `a` column to sort rows who have the same value in the `b` column

Comment: So what's the expected output?

Comment: @juanpethes not just the same values but also the same corresponding position of the values w.r.t  the first column b

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes, the rows are "coupled together". It won't mix around the rows; so in your example, the row with 4 in `b` always has `0` in the `a` column etc. It's not just two independent lists/Series

Answer (score 1):

For your data there is never tie in 1st column (in other words values in 1st column are unique), so no need to care about 2nd column, consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"b":[1,1,1,0,0,0],"a":[1,7,3,5,3,2]})
print(df.sort_values(by=['b', 'a']))
```

gives output

```
   b  a
5  0  2
4  0  3
3  0  5
0  1  1
2  1  3
1  1  7
```

Comment: So basically it considers , all individual items in the first column to be the same as the second column and also with their corresponding positions?  @Daweo

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a little over complicated but it works:

```py
import pandas as pd
```

```py
my_newobj = pd.DataFrame({'b': [4, 7, -3, 2], 'a': [0, 4, 7, 1]})
```

Separate the dataframes and drop the index values:

```py
a = my_newobj['a'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
b = my_newobj['b'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
# my_newobj['b'].sort_values(inplace=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Rejoin:

```py
final = pd.DataFrame()
final['b'] = b
final['a'] = a
```